# Cannot enter Sudo password when controlling Linux Mint with Synergy

Tags: linux, windows-8.1, linux-mint, synergy

I am running synergy 1.6.2 on a windows 8.1 Pro computer as the "Server". I am running Synergy 1.6.2 as a "Client" on Mint 17.1. When I take control of the Mint computer and try to perform tasks that require my sudo password I am consistently told that the password I am entering is incorrect. This happens when running commands through the terminal, or even when the Mint GUI requests my password for something as mundane as installing updates.

Is this a limitation of Synergy, or is there something I can do to get around this?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried opening a simple text editor on the Mint box, and seeing if you can enter your password there without issue?

Some special characters might not be making it through, and it would be the easiest way to tell if the password is getting sent correctly or not....

Comment: You were dead on. Turns out the Shift Key wasn't making it's way over to the client computer. Did some looking around and found a bunch of Windows 8.1 updates that cause this to happen. Got rid of the updates, restarted, and the problem went away. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

So Don Simon pointed me in the right direction on this one. Shift key was not making it over to the client. I used the following Synergy Bug Report:

https://github.com/synergy/synergy/issues/4055

Specifically this comment from emilsayad on October 20, 2014:

I went ahead and removed KB2993651, KB3000988, KB3000061, KB299817, KB2994897, KB2989542, KB2987107, KB2984006, KB2977174

And now everything is working as expected.